# How suppress selected columns in Outlook 2013 search results?

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013

Each time I search in Outlook 2013, the results include the Categories and Flagged columns, neither of which I ever want to see. How can I prevent these columns from showing up in search results?

Answer (score 1):

Search results are shown in the same view that the folder you start searching in, so to make sure you get the column you want you need to add/remove the columns for the folder in which you always search for emails before searching.

Comment: Now that you write that, I can't reproduce the problem, which has been plaguing me for weeks. I'll have to pay closer attention to exactly when it pops up, though until now, I thought it was always...